# I have a problem with log messages, and i can't solve it

Tags: logging, printing, lua

so i am trying to develop a message which can show strings and also the log, but oddly, the log only shows the last string and not the events in 1 message. can somebody help?

```lua
function printToLog(string, log)
    if logPage.fromMainMenu == false then             
      popupPage = logPage 
    else              
      logPage.fromMainMenu = true
      popupPage = logPage             
    end
                  
    prepareMenuPage(popupPage)
    local areYouSureText = getItemByName(logPage.items, "logText")
    setFont(areYouSureText.font)
    if log ~= true then
     areYouSureText.logText = string
     _G.table.insert(g_printLogList, string) -- insert string into log
     print(string)
    else
     for i = 1, #g_printLogList do
      areYouSureText.logText = g_printLogList[i]
     end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

**It's hard to debug without seeing** table construction, input values, what's expected, or at least an explaination, but I'll try.

This confuses me

```
if logPage.fromMainMenu == false then
    popupPage = logPage 
else                            --  if it isn't false...
    logPage.fromMainMenu = true  --  then it's already true.  no need to set it true here
    popupPage = logPage             
end
```

I wonder if was meant to be a comment

```
if logPage.fromMainMenu == false then             
    popupPage = logPage 
else  --  logPage.fromMainMenu = true
    popupPage = logPage             
end
```

But, if that were the case, you don't need the if...else - they're doing the exact same thing.  Perhaps you meant to flip it's value to the other?

```
if logPage.fromMainMenu == false then          
    logPage.fromMainMenu = true
end
popupPage = logPage
```

Either way, I think what's happening is that you are **replacing the entire contents** of `areYouSureText.logText` with one entry of `g_printLogList[i]` every time it loops.  What you actually mean to do, is append `areYouSureText.logText` with `g_printLogList[i]` during each loop.

```
for i = 1, #g_printLogList do
    areYouSureText.logText[ #areYouSureText.logText +1 ] = g_printLogList[i]
end
```

---

**Edit:**

Same difference, just append text with concatenation instead..

```
areYouSureText.logText = areYouSureText.logText ..'\n' ..g_printLogList[i]
```

Comment: the thing is that, areYouSureText.logText is actually a single value, and not a table